Doubt about this limit
I need to calculate
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \left(e^{1/x} - 1\right)\ln(e^x+1)$$
I thought about using Taylor series in this way
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right)\ln(e^x+1) = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x}\ln(e^x+1) + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(e^x+1)$$
The first term goes to $1$ by Hopital rule.
But what about the second one? I am not sure on how to treat little-o like this...
Is there a better way to calculate the limit? Initially I thought about Hopital but I got a mess.
P.s. I chose the tag "limits without Hopital" just as an alternative.

If you already know that $\frac{1}{x}\ln(e^x+1) \to 1$ then $o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(e^x+1) = o(1) \frac{1}{x}\ln(e^x+1)  \to 0$.

@MartinR Why does it go to zero considering that $\frac{1}{x} \ln(e^x+1) \to 1$? What is $o(1)$?

You can also write $o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(e^x+1) = \frac{o(1/x)}{1/x} \cdot \frac 1x \ln(e^x+1) \to 0 \cdot 1$.

It is well known that $$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1 $$
As $\dfrac{1}{x}\to 0$ when $x\to\infty$, we have $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{1/x}=1$$
Thus, the original limit must be the same as $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \dfrac{\ln(e^{x}+1)}{x}$$
Using L'Hôpital, we get that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \dfrac{\ln(e^{x}+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}=1$$

Consider the following
$$
\ln(e^x+1)=\ln\left[e^x\left(1+e^{-x}\right)\right]=\ln(e^x)+\ln(1+e^{-x})=x+\ln(1+e^{-x})
$$
Now use your Taylor series and multiply through this expression and notice that most everything goes to $0$, except for one term.
